# Where is information like note pitch, velocity, etc stored in Garageband project file/folder?

Tags: garageband, projects

I can't seem to find this information anywhere and my personal examination of Garageband project file/folders hasn't been that informative.

I'm trying to find where note information for various Garageband instruments (Smart instruments, Alchemy synths, and the like) is stored within the project file/folder.

I assumed (incorrectly I think) that it would be stored as a plain text MIDI file of some sort.  Unfortunately that is not the case.

I cannot find any information as to where that is stored from Apple nor various search engine searches.

Anyone have anything?

Comment: Knowing Apple's propensity for SQL, it wouldn't surprise me if it's in some similarly impenetrable form. Why not just save as a Midi file & interrogate that instead?

Comment: There's no way to save the contents of a "Smart" instrument nor even a Alchemy instrument as a MIDI file.  They can only be rendered as audio files.

I think your suggestion about SQL is good.  I'll look to see if I can spot anything that looks like a DB file.